# AngularJS: Why and when calling $timeout is required?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-timeout

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/ivevev/1/edit)

I created a `confirmationDialogHeader` directive which is used like so:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item}}
    <button class="btn btn-mini" 
            confirmation-dialog-header="Delete Item" 
            confirmation-dialog-action="deleteItem($index)">
      Delete
    </button>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

When the button is clicked, it is supposed to open a confirmation dialog, and if user confirms, it should call `deleteItem($index)`, and close the dialog.

My problem is with the last bit: **closing the dialog**.

Here is the controller (CoffeeScript):

```
app.controller 'AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$timeout', ($scope, $q, $timeout) ->
  $scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2'] 
  $scope.deleteItem = (index) ->                         
    deferred = $q.defer()
    $timeout ->
      $scope.items.splice(index, 1)   # All good if this line is removed
      deferred.resolve()
    , 1000
    deferred.promise
]
```

and here is the directive:

```
app.directive 'confirmationDialogHeader', ['$compile', '$q', ($compile, $q) ->
  restrict: 'A'
  scope:
    confirmationDialogAction: '@'
  controller: ($scope) ->
    $scope.onConfirm = ->
      $scope.$parent.$eval($scope.confirmationDialogAction).then ->
        $scope.confirmationDialog = off   # Why this doesn't close the dialog?
  link: (scope, element, attrs) -> 
    $confirmationDialog = $ """
      <div modal="confirmationDialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4>#{attrs.confirmationDialogHeader}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn" ng-click="confirmationDialog = false">
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button class="btn" ng-click="onConfirm()">
            Yes
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    """

    $(document.body).append($confirmationDialog)
    $compile($confirmationDialog)(scope)

    $(element).click ->
      scope.$apply ->
        scope.confirmationDialog = yes  

]
```

[As you can see](http://jsbin.com/ivevev/1/edit), **the dialog is not closed** after `deleteItem()` finishes and `$scope.confirmationDialog = off` is executed.

The interesting part is that, if `$scope.items.splice(index, 1)` is wrapped with `$timeout`, the dialog **is** closed properly!

```
$timeout ->
  $scope.items.splice(index, 1)
```

Why this `$timeout` wrapping is necessary here?

Are there any guidelines about when should we wrap code with `$timeout`?

---

[Working version of this directive that uses `$dialog`.](http://jsbin.com/execur/1/edit)

---

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any guidelines about when should we wrap code with $timeout?

$timeout is used as a replacement to the native setTimeout. The advantage over the native timeout is that it runs the callback in a try/catch block and any errors occurred will be forwarded to your applications exceptionHandler service.

However from my playing with your demo that is not the issue I am seeing and the code can be simplified.

**Update**
I was hoping to get your specific implementation using modal dialog working, but I didn't have much luck. So implemented it using the $dialog service rather than the modal directive. Maybe it will help - [here it is](http://plnkr.co/edit/g9PHcZ?p=preview)

Also, with your original version I found that the scope was being updated when you clicked yes to close the dialog and it was happening within a digest so it should have fired any watchers and thus close the dialog. In that regard I cannot see a reason why it was not working for whatever reason in my browser it made no difference whether or not timeout was used.

Comment: Code quality aside, this doesn't answer the OP's question. Why does it work with $timeout and not without? I've come across similar issues and sometimes adding the $timeout is necessary.

Comment: The demo actually doesn't work for me regardless of using $timeout. The OP asked if there were guidelines for using it - I would say I answered that. There is obviously some rather odd behaviour going on here which I haven't quite worked out.

Comment: @DerekEkins: What browser do you use?

Comment: I'm on Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110 (Fedora 17)